# Users getting removed from AD Group Automatically

Tags: remote-server, active-directory-group, domaincontroller

We have set of four servers. One server is domain control (DC) server and rest three servers are added under same domain. Apart from DC Server, rest all have SQL Server installed. I wanted to create a user group in DC server into which I can just add any user to provide remote desktop access to all servers.

To achieve this I did following settings:

- I created "Domain_Name\ReadOnlyUsers" group in DC Server only.
- Setting#1: Went to secpol.msc> Local Policies > User Rights Assignment > in 
  right side I added "Domain_Name\ReadOnlyUsers" group for "Allow logon through 
  Remote Desktop Services" policy
- Setting#2: Opened system properties by going through My Computer>Properties> 
  Remote Settings. In Remote page of System Properties dialog box I added the 
  "Domain_Name\ReadOnlyUsers" group to allow remote desktop connection.

I did above mentioned Setting#1 and 2 in all servers.

After doing all these settings, I created a user "domain_name\md" into DC Server only and added that user to "Domain_Name\ReadOnlyUsers" group. I was successfully able to login using that user into all servers. But after sometimes, this user is automatically getting removed from "Domain_Name\ReadOnlyUsers" group and after that I am not able to login using "domain_name\md" user. So in order to login into servers, I need to add this user manually into "Domain_Name\ReadOnlyUsers" group . Any solution to get rid of this automatic removal of this user?

OS Version: Windows Server 2012

Answer (score 0):

If you have AD auditing enabled, look for event 4738,4729,4733 to see who/what deleted the user from the group.

You should also look at GPO's.
Do a gpresult to see what policies are applied. My guess is that you have restricted groups policy set up.